# OrientDb: Error on unmarshalling JSON content when creating an edge

Tags: json, orientdb

I set up this piece of JSON to use with the OrientDb http API at url /batch/db.  I am trying to create an edge of class "cef_CONSISTSOF_cef" which is subclassed from "E".

```
{"transaction":true, 
 "operations":[ 
    {"type":"c", 
     "record":{ 
        "@class":"cef_CONSISTSOF_cef", 
        "out":"#12:37847", 
        "in":"#12:37641"}
       } 
  ]}
```

In response I get the following:

```
{ "errors": [ 
   { "code": 500, "reason": 500, 
  "content": 
    "com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OSerializationException: Error on unmarshalling JSON content 
  '{\"transaction\":true,\"operations\":[{\"type\":\"c\",\"record\":
    {\"@class': content must be between { }" } ] }
```

Any ideas on what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your case with this following simple dataset and by using Postman and OrientDB 2.1.15

[image]

I can give you two options to create the edge througt HTTP request:

1. **USING `"type" : "cmd"`:**

[image]

[image]

**STUDIO:**

[image]

2. **USING `"type" : "script"`:**

[image]

[image]

**STUDIO:**

[image]

**EDITED**

1. **USING `"type" : "c"`:**

[image]

[image]

**STUDIO:**

[image]

[image]

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks.  Your answers suggest that I should not expect the original version to work.  Is that correct?

Comment: Hi, I edited my answer. I was checking your code and it seemed to work for me but, if you look at the last picture, the edge `#13:7` is created in the class `cef_CONSISTSOF_cef` but non correctly displayed in Studio. I tried and chose the options that returned all the correct results. Hope to have been helpful.